# CSP google tag manager issue in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, content-security-policy

In my landing page(ejs) I have the snippet of google tag manager, but I have the CSP that doesn't allow inline scripts.. on the server-side(app.js) I generate on each request a nonce id.

```
const nonceToken = 'nonce-' + crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
```

the code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        nounceToken: nonceToken
    })
});
```

this is the snippet inside the ejs file:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
                'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
            }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
                    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-*******');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

in the helmet options :

```
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
        "script-src-elem": ["'self'", "https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal", "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-*******"],
        "form-action": 'self',
        "script-src": 'nonce-' + nonceToken,
    }
}));
```

Errors given in the console of Google:

**The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src-elem' contains a source with an invalid path: '/gtm.js?id=GTM-*******'. The query component, including the '?', will be ignored.**

and also:

**Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal [https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-*******"](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-*******%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1KheQ9YFAlUN7PPKDGu2i9+u4UTLBUuJvOgrQJPK1lg='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.**

i have tried a tons of times to find a solution to that but nothing..

Answer (score 1):

1. The `const nonceToken = 'nonce-' + crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');` gives you `nonce-ab3d5...ef` string already starting with `nonce-`. But in Helmet settings you add `nonce-` string once more: `"script-src": 'nonce-' + nonceToken,` therefore you'll get `'nonce-nonce-ab3d5...ef'` token.
2. The `nonce-value` token should be a single-quoted: `'nonce-value'`.
3. Google Tag Manager's inline script in the snippet inside the `ejs` file does not contains `nonce='ab3d5...ef'` attribute therefore it will be blocked. You have to use `<script nonce='ab3d5...ef'>...</script>` tag with the valid nonce attribute.
4. In the Helmet you use the `script-src-elem` direcive in pair with the `script-src`. Only Chrome browser supports the `script-src-elem`, (other browsers will use the `script-src`).
   So Chrome will use `script-src-elem": 'self'", "https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal", "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-*******"` which does not contain `'nonce-value'` token.
   Other browsers will use `"script-src": 'nonce-' + nonceToken` therefore they will not allow external scripts which do not have `nonce='ab3d5...ef'` attribute (as `<script src='...' nonce='ab3d5...ef'>`).
5. The `https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal` host-source do not have a trailing slash `/` therefore `scrollreveal` will be treated as file name but not folder name. Any source like `https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js` will be prohibited whereas `https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/` allows it.
6. The host-sources like `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=...` with a query-string component are not allowed in CSP, therefore you have to use `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js` or `https://www.googletagmanager.com`.

So finally you need to modify you code a little bit:

```
const nonceToken = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');  // To remove "'nonce-' +"

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script nonce='${nonceToken}'>(function (w, d, s, l, i) { // To add nonce='ab3d5...ef' attribute
        w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
            'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-*******');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
        "script-src": ["'self'", `'nonce-${nonceToken}'`, "https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/", "https://www.googletagmanager.com"],
        "form-action": 'self',
        // Other CSP directives which differs from useDefaults() here
    }
}));
```

If I understand correctly, the `${nonceToken}` should output a real value of nonceToken. Although in the Electron is usually used construction like:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.cspNonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex"); // res.locals.cspNonce will be available everywhere
    next();
    });

app.use((req, res, next) =>
    helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
      useDefaults: true,
      directives: {
        ...
        scriptSrc: [
          `'nonce-${res.locals.nonce}'`,
          "'self'",
          "https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/",
          "https://www.googletagmanager.com"
        ],
      },
    })(req, res, next))
```